# How to get the disk capacity and free space of unattached disks in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-storage-files

I have been researching, but is there a way to get the disk capacity and free space of unattached disks in Azure?

Comment: Hi, has your issue been solved?

Comment: @Stanley Gong, yeah, that was a great answer. All I now have to do is to always attach the disk as a data disk to a running VM. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't get a free space of unattached disks. If it is necessary to do so , you should attach it to an Azure VM so that you can use run command feature of Azure VMs to run a [PowerShell script on windows VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command) or run a [shell script on Linux VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command) to get free disk space directly.

If you want to get disk capacity, you can use [rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/disks/get) or SDK or Powershell command  below to get it directly:

```
$disk = Get-AzDisk -DiskName <disk name> -ResourceGroupName <resource group name>
$disk.DiskSizeGB
```

[image]

Comment: that was a great answer. All I now have to do is to always attach the disk as a data disk to a running VM. Thanks so much.